# How is google cloud storage different from file storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-filestore

Google cloud storage has buckets which are similar to folders and objects which are files, so besides the naming changes, what are the other differences between the two?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage has some specific features that differentiate it from a proper file system:

- It doesn't actually provide directories/folders, it only implements buckets and objects, i.e there's no concept of folders, nested directories, etc... See doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#object-considerations) for more details about that.
- It doesn't implement file modification. When you upload an update to an existing object, it actually [replaces](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#immutability) that object altogether with the new version (versioning is available though).

Google Cloud Filestore provides managed NFS file servers as a fully managed service on GCP. It is meant to provide high-performance file storage capabilities to applications running on Compute Engine and Kubernetes Engine instances.

Comment: An analogy that help me is to look at Google Cloud Storage like an AWS bucket (object storage) accessed over an gRPC or HTTP API but Google Filestore is accessed from your application like a locally mounted (highly available) NAS drive.